# How do I bridge objc typedef NSString to Swift as String?

Tags: swift

Say I have some objc code:

```
typedef NSString * ObjcNSString;

@interface ObjC : NSObject
+ (void)doThingsWithString:(nullable ObjcNSString)mid;
@end
```

The corresponding generated Swift interface for the objc code above is:

```
public typealias ObjcNSString = NSString

open class ObjC : NSObject {
    open class func doThings(with mid: String?)
}
```

This is causing problem if I use the code in Swift:

```
let str: ObjcNSString? = nil
ObjC.doThings(with: str) // Cannot convert value of type 'ObjcNSString?' (aka 'Optional<NSString>') to expected argument type 'String?'
```

But I really want to use the `ObjcNSString` type in Swift, is there any way to make it work?

Comment: Why do you have the `typedef` and `typealias`? Why do you want to use `NSString` in Swift?

Comment: Also why are implementing same class(ObjC) in both Swift and ObjectiveC?. Also you are trying to call Swift class function only by "ObjC.doThings(with: str)". So It should expect "String?" parameter only.

Comment: I'm not implementing the same class in both Swift and Objective-C, the Swift code for `ObjC` class is the generated Swift interface for the objc code.

Comment: You really want to get rid of the `ObjcNSString` typedef. That's just creating a mess of everything here. It's not the underlying problem; it doesn't break anything itself; it's just causing you confusion that's leading you to write incorrect code for no reason (as matt explains below). Use `NSString *` in ObjC and `String` in Swift, and everything will just work. (There is definitely ways to make `ObjcNSString` work in Swift; it does work in Swift; but it's going to constantly bite you for no reason. You'd better have a *really* compelling use care here that you should explain.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The answer is to use `NS_SWIFT_BRIDGED_TYPEDEF`

As the title of the question:

> How do I bridge objc typedef NSString to Swift as String?

I found `NS_SWIFT_BRIDGED_TYPEDEF`, use that for an ObjC typedef of NSString, then the type will be bridged as String to Swift.

## Example

#### Without `NS_SWIFT_BRIDGED_TYPEDEF`

```
typedef NSString * ObjcNSString;

@interface ObjC : NSObject
+ (void)doThingsWithString:(nullable ObjcNSString)mid;
@end
```

The corresponding Swift interface is:

```
public typealias ObjcNSString = NSString

open class ObjC : NSObject {

    open class func doThings(with mid: String?)
}
```

And that will give me error when I do this:

```
let str: ObjcNSString? = nil
ObjC.doThings(with: str) // Cannot convert value of type 'ObjcNSString?' (aka 'Optional<NSString>') to expected argument type 'String?'
```

#### With `NS_SWIFT_BRIDGED_TYPEDEF`

Add `NS_SWIFT_BRIDGED_TYPEDEF` for the ObjC typedef:

```
typedef NSString * ObjcNSString NS_SWIFT_BRIDGED_TYPEDEF;

@interface ObjC : NSObject
+ (void)doThingsWithString:(nullable ObjcNSString)mid;
@end
```

Then the Swift interface becomes:

```
public typealias ObjcNSString = String

open class ObjC : NSObject {

    open class func doThings(with mid: ObjcNSString?)
}
```

And the same code compiles:

```
let str: ObjcNSString? = nil
ObjC.doThings(with: str)
```

So I achieved my goal:

> But I really want to use the ObjcNSString type in Swift

---

If you look close to the difference between the Swift interfaces with or without `NS_SWIFT_BRIDGED_TYPEDEF`, you'll see by adding `NS_SWIFT_BRIDGED_TYPEDEF` we get a more desired Swift interface.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the code that was generated is not quite what you want.

The error you are getting is saying that your function is expecting a `String` type, but you are trying to use a `ObjcNSString` type.

To fix this, just change your function declaration to:

`open class func doThings(with mid: ObjcNSString?)`

But keep in mind, you can just use NSString in Swift.  You don't need the typealias.  You can just as well write your function like:

`open class func doThings(with mid: NSString?)`